# Running GWT through through IntelliJ gives "Plugin failed to connect to Development Mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997" but it works fine through eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, intellij-idea

I have a multimodule gwt project that I'm able to start up and run through IntelliJ just fine. But when I go to debug the application (or actually just the act of adding ?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 to the end of the url) causes me to get the dreaded "Plugin failed to connect to Development Mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997.

My current setup is:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Entrypoint has a dependency on several portal modules. I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong, because the portal runs fine as long as it's not through the code server..

Edit: Here is my current run configuration. I've tried everything including changing the -war directory to target\ROOT and src\main\webapp and I've changed the web facet resource folder to the same, I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Note that I've tried removing and adding the bindAddress several times. It doesn't differently either way.

Answer (score 2):

It is not your Project Structure that is at fault here. Most probably your "Run Configuration" has flaws. In "Run/Debug Configurations" you need to create "GWT Configuration" and set up properties correctly. I run with "GWT Module to load" = "All" and with "Dev Mode parameters" set to "-bindAddress 0.0.0.0" to allow accessing my debug config from various hosts, not only from localhost - you may or may not need it. Obviously, for your setup "Use Super Dev mode" should be turned off.

Also you need to check that the port 9997 is not taken up by another process. But if it is, you will see the error in Jetty's startup log in debug console. I assume if it works with Eclipse it should not be.

Comment: I upgraded my comment. I've done all of that before and again and it still doesn't work.

Comment: The only difference is - I do not have "-server ..." option in Dev Mode parameters. Also, Stack Size of 512 meg?! Please use -Xss512k, however even deep stack traces with mild recursions get away with -Xss128k; keep in mind each thread you start will consume 512 meg in your current configuration.

Comment: I used the server option because I was getting this error https://community.jboss.org/thread/197015?tstart=0&_sscc=t and that was the suggested fix. It worked. I also didn't know what the -Xss512m did, I just used it because a coworked told me that our app needed it.

Comment: I am 100% sure about Xss, 512k is enough to keep up with deepest JBoss+Spring stacks. Large stacks will severely impact performance, at the very least. It is hard to say what exactly is wrong with your setup without learning much more about your solution. From experience, if you can run it in Eclipse, you can 100% run it in IDEA. Your "-server" setting seems to be ok. I would add -logLevel DEBUG and carefully examine the log. I run multi-module GWT + multiple separate WAR apps in IDEA/Jetty Dev Mode with no pain and with full in-IDE debug capabilities.

Comment: Oh, and it might be as simple as clearing all caches: browser, IDEAs "File - Invalidate Caches/Restart", in $USER/.IntelliJIdea13/system/gwt (you can safely remove it at any time between runs), and mabe delete and re-install GWT browser plugin.

Comment: Ok running with the -logLevel DEBUG I get some funny looking comments like "Linking Private artifacts into NULL" but then I see others that look like "Linking Deploy artifacts into C:\Users\tyler.thrailkill\.IntelliJIdea13\system\gwt\Dart2.4788fe47\portal-entrypoint.daf73ab3\run\www\WEB-INF\deploy" so I'm not sure if those are actually bad or not. I'm getting the dreaded Gwt module may need to be recompiled error consistently now, instead of a hanging screen, so I'm unsure of what I changed. Also I started completely anew by reimporting the main modules into a new IntelliJ project.

Comment: oh and I guess I should mention, I've gotten other gwt projects working fine in IntelliJ, but they weren't multi module.

Comment: So I tried everything you said, invalidating caches, removing and reinstalling gwt browser plugin, and removing the folder. None of them worked, I still get a gwt module may need to be recompiled error, which I've tried every solution for.

Comment: Also, when I'm importing the projects, do I need to choose the "Exclude build directory (%PROJECT_ROOT%/target)" or "Use Maven output directories" options?